# How to calculate the Mult-Adds of transformer as mentioned in Lite Transformer

Tags: time-complexity, transformer-model

How to calculate the Mult-Adds of transformer as mentioned in Lite Transformer so that For the attention layer, the Mult-Adds would be O(4N d2 + N 2d); for FFN, the Mult-Adds is O(2 × 4N d2).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEgvg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxxQc.jpg)